# React / Flux - fetch all data after every update/add/remove

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm learning React and Flux and there's something that bothers me about all the examples I've seen so far.
They all are pretty much a CRUD UI.
In them, they always fetch all the data after every change (update/add/delete etc.)
So let's say, we have a todo app, and the user added a new todo item.
In a response, the store will get an action, call some API in the server to add the item and then fetch all the items again.
Isn't that expensive?
I understand why it makes things simpler which is good. But, why not add the item to the store's state. I understand this makes it so you always have the keep the store and the data in the server synced like that but it's not as expensive.

One solution I saw was pagination but in the example they would still get all the items for the new page every time a user changes it.

1. Why always fetch all the data?
2. If we use pagination - would we get the new page from the server every time a user changes pages?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to get data after every change. In the apps that I have built, I have always changed the store rather than get all data.

In only one project which involved DreamFactory API, we used to refresh the model (only that model/item) after an update. That was necessary because DreamFactory API pulls all the related data in a single call.

Comment: Would you say that if I have a lot of data (let's say 1000+ items) it's worth using pagination with querying the server for every update? Because keeping all the items in the store seems like a massive memory problem. Maybe that's the gist behind why they always reload the data.

Comment: It should not be a problem with modern browsers to handle 10,000 items in the store. Pagination is not always good, especially for enterprise apps. Datagrids like zippy-ui/react-datagrid or ag-grid claim they can handle upto 50,000 or even million rows on the browser. For consumer applications, pagination makes more sense. The idea is not to overwhelm users with too much data. Browsers can handle 1000 items very easily.